# SQL selection in SQL, doesn't work as intended

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I have 3 variables that comes from form input, and I have this selection in php
If I'm searching in input `$itemName`, it return me exact one item, as it needs, if I'm searching in `$typeName` or `$itemPrice`, it return me entire list of item, that is not ok, I try to do `'%$typeName%'` and `'%$itemPrice'` as I did for `$itemName`, but anyway it return me all list. what is the problem?

```
$stid = oci_parse($conn, "select title, type, price
                          from items 
                          where title like '%$itemName%' 
                             or type like '$typeName' 
                             or price like '$itemPrice'");
```

Comment: Please read using [prepared statements in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: The  `LIKE '%...%'` matches any string that is part of the string - meaning that if you get values like `'Camel' LIKE '%me%'` would be true for that row. You need to be more explicit with your question for us to get a clue what you're trying to do - show the table-data, the values for each variable and what result you expect to get.

Comment: The problem is that if you have $itemName as '', I mean, an empty string, when you do **like '%$itemName%'**, is the same as if you do **like '%%', so it gets all rows, because all of them match

Comment: @Qirel, if I type for example 'Iphone', that is one of the items, in the $itemName, it display only one item, that is true, cause it's only one item with this name, I have only one item with type of 'Cellular',but instead of returning this one item, it return all of them, so why '%$itemName%', returning as it needs, but '%$typeName%' returning all items?

Comment: You MUST use bind variables otherwise you will have a SQL Injection security hole.  See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php  Also see "Binding With LIKE and REGEXP_LIKE Clauses" on page 168 of https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html

Answer (score 0):

A generic solution for binding with LIKE is:

```
<?php
$c = oci_connect("hr", "welcome", "localhost/XE");
$s = oci_parse($c,
    "select city, state_province from locations where city like :bv");
$city = 'South%';
oci_bind_by_name($s, ":bv", $city);
oci_execute($s);
oci_fetch_all($s, $res);
var_dump($res);
?>
```

You must use binding to avoid SQL Injection security issues of concatenating variable values into the SQL string.  It also helps performance and scalability.

See "Binding With LIKE and REGEXP_LIKE Clauses" on page 168 of in https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html

Answer (score -2):

Try using single qoutation mark

```php
$stid = oci_parse($conn, 'Select title, type, price from items 
                          where title like '%$itemName%' 
                             or type like '$typeName' 
                             or price like '$itemPrice'');
```

Comment: That code har syntax errors, because you use singlequotes both for the string and in SQL. It would also mean that PHP variables will not get parsed, so this is a step in the wrong direction.

Comment: Sorry my bad, maybe concatenating variables will work

Comment: That will change nothing, as PHP variables are parsed with their values within double quotes. You don't have to concatenate them then. See https://www.php.net/types.string